# Does the repeater control support two way model data binding

Tags: c#, .net, webforms

- ASP.NET 4.51
- With the "new" model binding functionality (http://www.sitepoint.com/asp-net-4-5-strongly-typed-data-controls-model-binding/) I can do 2 way model binding with:

However I am guessing that because there is no UpdateMethod exposed for a repeater it does not support two way binding even though I can use two way binding syntax within its item template?

Second question. Is there a definitive list of what controls support two way model binding? Is it only ListView, FormView, GridView or are there others?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to further usage it only supports one way model binding.